# Why XInput can't work in X-treminal?

Tags: linux, x11, xinput

I try show keyboard event by app **xinput**. I trying at three workstation. At first two workstaion (in local X-session) is all good:

Get device list:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer id=2 [master pointer (3)]
⎜  ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer id=4 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜  ↳ HID 1241:1177 id=8 [slave pointer (2)]
⎜  ↳ SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard id=10 [slave pointer (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard id=3 [master keyboard (2)]
   ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard id=5 [slave keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button id=6 [slave keyboard (3)]
   ↳ Power Button id=7 [slave keyboard (3)]
   ↳ SIGMACH1P USB Keykoard id=9 [slave keyboard (3)]
```

Device event:

```
$ xinput test 9
key release 36
key press 48
key press 47
key release 48
key press 46
lkey release 47
key release 46
key press 41
key press 36
key release 41
key release 36
key press 62
key release 62
key press 37
```

But! To three workstation i connect from X-terminal **x2go** (connect from Windows 7). And in this workstation xinpunt does not fulfill its function. Xinput does not find devices and show segfault:

```
$ xinput
"pointer"   id=0    [XPointer]
"keyboard"  id=1    [XKeyboard]

$ xinput test 1
unable to find device '1'

$ xinput test-xi2 1
"keyboard"  id=1    [XKeyboard]
    Num_keys is 248
    Min_keycode is 8
    Max_keycode is 255
Segmentation fault
```

**Question 1:** The **xinput** principial does not work if connection to X-server stable from X-terminal? Or it is bug in standart X11 application?

**Question 2:** How to alternative get global keyboard event (push and release key) if connect from X-terminal (x2go)?

Environment:
From connect: Windows 7 Pro, official X2GO client from site x2go.org.
To connect: Debian 7.8, LXDE, official server X2GO from site x2go.org.

Comment: This may be better asked at http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: UNIX stackexchange is silent: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288780/why-xinput-cant-work-in-x-terminal

Comment: Where get real specialist of X-server?